# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'file:/.../Sample/my-app/target/lib/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have created a simple SpringBoot project using maven and my only class present is App.java containing

```
package com.mycompany.app;

// import org.slf4j.Logger;
// import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {

    // Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
    
    @GetMapping("/test-docker")
    public String getData() {
        return "in docker tutorial project of example";
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // System.out.println("SOP method");
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.1</version>
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- <pluginManagement>lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    <!-- </pluginManagement> -->
  </build>
</project>
```

When I do a mvn install, the jar file is created in my target directory. When I run the following command,

```
java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get the error:

```
lrd72218673:my-app subnara$ java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load factories from location [META-INF/spring.factories]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:151)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:428)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:420)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:268)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:249)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:24)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open root Jar file 'file:/Users/subnara/Documents/Code/DevOps/MicroServices+Docker+Kubernetes/Sample/my-app/target/lib/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar'
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.getRootJarFile(Handler.java:344)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.getRootJarFileFromUrl(Handler.java:325)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:99)
        at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1126)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:170)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:133)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:122)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:139)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /Users/subnara/Documents/Code/DevOps/MicroServices Docker Kubernetes/Sample/my-app/target/lib/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar must exist
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.openIfNecessary(RandomAccessDataFile.java:234)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.<init>(RandomAccessDataFile.java:216)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.<init>(RandomAccessDataFile.java:206)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile.<init>(RandomAccessDataFile.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:88)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.getRootJarFile(Handler.java:338)
        ... 23 more
```

I am a noob in this area and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` maven plugin and take a look at https://start.spring.io/.

When I try to reproduce the problem:

- create a folder with the specified pom.xml and App.java file in it
- run `mvn install in the folder`
- run `java -jar target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I don't run into the problem.

Since we are using the same code (assuming your question contains the same code as you were using), I wonder whether the problem might be related to your version of Maven and Java. I am using Maven 3.6.3 and java 11.0.11.

That being said, I noticed the build configuration in your pom is rather complex. It can be simplified significantly using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Since your issue seems to be related to missing libraries and this spring-boot plugin also handles adding these libraries to the generated jar, switching to this plugin might also solve your problems.

Since you mention you just created the project, I would like to suggest you take a look at https://start.spring.io/. It's a too to bootstrap new spring boot projects. One advantage, and the reason I'd suggest it to you, is that it generates a project that *should* work. You don't have to figure out which plugins or dependencies to add, the generator does that for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was using VS Code. Now I tried IntelliJ using the spring starter link you mentioned. It works like a charm!!!